# Using JavaScript to set an attribute for file type inputs

Tags: javascript, html, attributes

I'm trying to make it so some of the file type inputs on my website would only accept images using JavaScript.

As per my understanding I need to give selected file type inputs the attribute `accept` with the value `image/*`. I'm trying to use `Element.setAttribute()` for this but can't get it to work as I'm new to JavaScript and don't know the fundamentals and the correct structure the code should be in.

I tried making it work for at least one of the file type inputs like so:

```
function myFunction() {
  var element = document.getElementById("woo_message_attachment");
  element.setAttribute("accept", "image/*");
}
```

It didn't work. I would appreciate if someone could please explain why and show me the proper way to achieve what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: It would seem like there is something else causing your problem because your logic and code both seem fine. If I run 'myFunction()' on a page with a file input that has that id, it works as intended. Are you sure myFunction() is being run on the page?

Comment: Can you show your full HTML?

Comment: @EssXTee, how do I specify which page the function should run on? I'm a WordPress user and always just paste the JavaScript code snippets in a place dedicated for them that's provided by my WP theme.

Comment: how is myFunction called?

Comment: @code, is this enough? `<input type="file" multiple="" name="woo_attach[]" id="woo_message_attachment">`

Comment: @epascarello, here's the thing, I have no idea. I saw an example of a similar situation online and just tried to make it work.. I don't know what `function myFunction()` does, the example I found online had it at the beginning, so I used it as well..

Comment: well if you do not call a function, the function does not execute. So that code inside never would run....

Comment: @JOKKER can you paste your _entire_ HTML here? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So it seems the issue is that you are not actually calling myFunction() anywhere, and are not sure when/where to call it since you don't have full control over what pages this script is on.

One possible solution is to have the function trigger after the page has loaded. Then you would check to make sure that element exists on the page, and lastly change the 'accept' attribute.

Try adding something like this to your global javascript in wordpress:

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  if(document.getElementById("woo_message_attachment") !== null) {
document.getElementById("woo_message_attachment").setAttribute("accept", "image/*");
  }
});
```